# How to load a self-made TIFF image file from NSDocumentsDirectory

Tags: objective-c, tiff, nsdocumentdirectory, cgimagesource

When trying to load files from the `NSDocumentsDirectory` of an iPhone, I cannot create the image source with the path string I have.

I get the error message "`<Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -15.`", which is a `kCFURLImproperArgumentsError`.

However, I cannot find what "proper" arguments might be. An example path would be: "`/var/mobile/Applications/36D76BDF-72EC-4180-9246-CF1F50CF396C/Documents/2013080110555532Image.tiff`"

In my question [How to save a TIFF...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361100/how-to-save-a-tiff-photo-from-avfoundations-capturestillimageasynchronouslyfromc), I now document how I write the files to the `NSDocumentsDirectory`. Thanks again for the help, folks.

Now I *try to* read them again. I *thought* the reading was like the writing, only mirrored.
The files are ~20MB - ...ahem, ...each! - that might be a problem as well...

This is a code snippet (thanks to [Ganapathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545180/ganapathy) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443562/ios-best-way-to-store-the-downloaded-images/17443917) answer) that actually gives me an image to display:

```
if ([self pathLastRawDataSave])
{
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self pathLastRawDataSave]];

    if (NULL != anImage)
    {
        [[self imageView] setImage:anImage];
    }
}
```

*However*, it is always more complicated than in a small example and I also need the metadata (and a thumbnail of the image), so I fear I am back to make the `CGImageSource` work, after all.

**Heureka! I have found it! The missing link was the method** `fileURLWithPath`**!**
Apart from that I am not caching and also using the create options dictionary for the image retrieval.

This is actually working:

```
if ([self pathLastRawDataSave])
{
    NSURL* imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self pathLastRawDataSave]];

    CFURLRef imageFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL; // bridged from NS-Object, no release!

    NSDictionary* sourceOptions = @{(id)kCGImageSourceShouldCache: (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
                                    (id)kCGImageSourceTypeIdentifierHint: (id)kUTTypeTIFF};

    CFDictionaryRef sourceOptionsRef = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)sourceOptions; // bridged from NS-Object, no release!

    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageFileURLRef, sourceOptionsRef);


    if (NULL != imageSource)
    {
        // create the image from the file
        CGImageRef imageData = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, sourceOptionsRef);

        // release core foundation object
        CFRelease(imageSource);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error opening image file
        HLSLoggerFatal(@"Image source could not be accessed at path %@", [self pathLastRawDataSave]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Heureka! I have found it! The missing link was the method** `fileURLWithPath`**!**
Apart from that I am not caching and also using the create options dictionary for the image retrieval.

This is actually working:

```
if ([self pathLastRawDataSave])
{
    NSURL* imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self pathLastRawDataSave]];

    CFURLRef imageFileURLRef = (__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL; // bridged from NS-Object, no release!

    NSDictionary* sourceOptions = @{(id)kCGImageSourceShouldCache: (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
                                    (id)kCGImageSourceTypeIdentifierHint: (id)kUTTypeTIFF};

    CFDictionaryRef sourceOptionsRef = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)sourceOptions; // bridged from NS-Object, no release!

    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageFileURLRef, sourceOptionsRef);


    if (NULL != imageSource)
    {
        // create the image from the file
        CGImageRef imageData = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, sourceOptionsRef);

        // release core foundation object
        CFRelease(imageSource);
    }
    else
    {
        // Error opening image file
        HLSLoggerFatal(@"Image source could not be accessed at path %@", [self pathLastRawDataSave]);
    }
}
```